# How to create a new run in ALM

Tags: c#, xml, rest, alm

I am trying to call ALM REST api using postman , i am able to do the basic stuff like login , authentication, and other things also like using GET method for getting TEST-SET, TEST-INSTANCE, .
I am taking the return in XML format,

Similar way i am trying to update also using PUT method , tried updating test-set name , that too worked for me , now, my question is How to create a new run if i have all the required fields value with me in a XML format, 
My main aim to have it integrated with C# Application. 
Using Postman i am just testing the restAPI's.

Here is what i am trying to create a new run :

```
https://yourdomainName/qcbin/rest/domains/Default/projects/PROJECTNAME/runs
```

My XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entity Type="run">
    <Fields>
        <Field Name="name">
            <Value>Run_9-21_6-58-2</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="test-instance">
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="test-config-id">
            <Value>189788</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="testcycl-id">
            <Value>1541011</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="cycle-id">
            <Value>77859</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="test-id">
            <Value>154070</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="subtype-id">
            <Value>hp.qc.run.MANUAL</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="owner">
            <Value>demouser</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="status"><Value>Not Completed</Value>
        </Field>
    </Fields>
</Entity>
```

I am getting this error while calling PUT method :

```
Unexpected failure in getValuePostProcess

Exception Id: qccore.general-error
```

If any body has any idea please help , i am totally stuck.

Comment: What is the question? What does happen when you send this XML?

Comment: i added the error , i think their is problem with the format i am trying to send , but can't figure out the error , so not so sure. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Try these in sequence :
"<Entity Type=\"run\"><Fields>
<Field Name=\"name\"><Value> name</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"test-id\"><Value>" + test_id + "</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"testcycl-id\"><Value>" + testcycl_id + "</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"owner\"><Value> OwnerName</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"status\"><Value>Passed</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"subtype-id\"><Value> SubtypeID</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"execution-date\"><Value>ExecutionDate</Value></Field>
</Fields></Entity>
```

Comment: what is your question?? You neither wrote a title!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of HTTPS use HTTP and use PUT call, e.g.

```
PUT
http://HOSTNAME:80/qcbin/rest/domains/WHOLESALE/projects/PROJECTNAME/runs/%ID%
```

In your case:

```
http://yourdomainName/qcbin/rest/domains/Default/projects/PROJECTNAME/runs/%ID%
```